# Need help with tricky vector math. Limit magnitude of vector only in direction tangent to sphere.

Tags: vectors, rotations, transformation

I need helping figuring out some vector math for a project I am working on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Image a point like object, *P*, orbiting a sphere planet. *P* has a velocity vector associated with it that is manipulated by gravity and external acceleration. I want to limit the velocity of the object tangentially to the sphere, while preserving the velocity of the object in the direction toward the center of the sphere (gravity).

Variables:

```
 A normal 3D vector (vector from center of planet to point): *N*
 A velocity 3D vector: *V*
 A point 3D (origin of velocity vector): *P*
 A point 3D (origin planet): (0, 0, 0)
```

Goal: Limit the magnitude of *V* to some value *x* but only in the direction tangent to the sphere planet.

Thank you for your help I just cannot figure this out.

Comment: Questions that follow the structure "Here's my question, answer it for me" are quite poorly recieved. Try mentioning what you've tried, any challenges you've faced, or anything to show that you've attempted to solve the question.

Comment: Not a consulting site.

Comment: Express your vector in spherical coordinates. multiply the tangential component by $x$ divided by the norm of the tangential component, convert the vector back to cartesian coordinates.